# Is $ f(z) = (\bar {z})^2 - 5z $ differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Since the complex conjugate is not differentiable, can I immediately conclude that $ f= (\bar{z})^2 - 5z$ is also not differentiable at any point?

Ignoring the $5z$ for a moment, the formal definition of the derivative yields the following for $f(z) = (\bar{z})^2 $:

$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(z+h) - f(z)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{ 2\bar{z}\bar{h} + (\bar{h})^2}{h}$

And if I'm not mistaken, the limit does not exist.

Comment: "Since the complex conjugate is not differentiable, can I immediately conclude that..." - No. It is not difficult to construct real or complex functions that, while they are the sum/product of nondifferentiable functions, the function overall is. Consider the Dirichlet function on the reals, which is $0$ at rational points and $1$ at irrational points. Consider that to be $f$ for example. Define $g$ to be the same except swapping the $0$ and $1$ around. $f,g$ are not differentiable anywhere but $f+g$ is constant.

Comment: The $\bar{z}^2$ cancel

Comment: You forgot to subtract the $f(z)$

Comment: Neil and Hamidine, you are right, corrected.  Still I don't see a limit existing.

Comment: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=2\bar{z}$ is not zero, so $f$ is definitely not holomorphic. Now, I am not sure about "every point".

Answer (score 1):

To check for complex differentiability - especially when $\bar z$ occurs - you may use the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations):

- Write $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ and check where $u_x = v_y, u_y = -v_x$ are satisfied simultaneously.

$$\bar z^2-5z = ({x-iy})^2 - 5(x+iy) = x^2-5x-y^2 + i(-2xy-5)$$
$$\Rightarrow u(x,y) = x^2-5x-y^2, v(x,y)= -2xy-5y$$
$$\Rightarrow  u_x = 2x-5, u_y=-2y,v_x = -2y,v_y=-2x-5$$
Now you get
$$u_x=v_y \Leftrightarrow x=0; u_y=-v_x \Leftrightarrow y=0$$

It follows $f(z)\bar z^2-5z$ is complex **differentiable only at** $\boxed{z=0}$. Anywhere else the Cauchy-Riemann equations are not satisfied simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

The limit indeed doesn't exist, because it depends on the path taken. Take $h=\epsilon$ and you get $2\bar{z}$, while for $h=i\epsilon$ you get $-2\bar{z}$. Note that it means that your function *is* differentiable at $z=0$.

Another way to prove the limit doesn't exist is to use the [Cauchy–Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations). It is essentially the same as taking different paths and requiring the results to be the same, yet it is a straight-forward way to show stuff without actually calculating limits.